# MSVC15 Linking error LNK2019

Tags: c++, lnk2019

Yes, I have read the documentation about the LNK2019 error, however I can't figure out what is actually causing the problem since the error message is quite random to me.

*The application is quite large, so can anyone perhaps conclude something out of just the error message alone*?

The error:

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > __cdecl explode(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?explode@@YA?AV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@0@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl GetWords(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (?GetWords@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEAV12@@Z)
```

**(Yes I have already set the Runtime-Library)**

Comment: Please include the line of code that causes this error.

Comment: It looks like the function you are trying to use it not defined in any of the files you are compiling.

Comment: @GraysonPike I would actually love to however it tells me the error occurs on line 1 which leads to `#include "stdafx.h"`

Comment: It looks like you have not linked in the explode() function, whatever that might be - it's not part of Standard C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, please add it as an answer... unbelievable you can understand such error messages. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My difficulty with the error was with the format of the error message. The linker tells you exactly what is wrong. Although it is pretty verbose..

Comment: @NathanOliver, indeed thanks a lot. It was my `explode` function like Neil stated